# how to check CGMutablePathRef is null or not

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-graphics

i have a CGMutablePathRef object called **path**, i want to know, how can i know **path** is null, it means i didn't use

```
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, point.y);
```

or

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
```

to push points into path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether a path is NULL, use the `==`/`!=` operator.

```
if (path != NULL)
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, point.y);
```

To check whether a path contains no nothing, use [CGPathIsEmpty](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html).

```
if (!CGPathIsEmpty(path))
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, point.y);
```

To check whether a path's point has been moved, use [CGPathGetCurrentPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000959-CH1g-CGPathGetCurrentPoint) and compare with (0, 0).

```
if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(CGPathGetCurrentPoint(path), CGPointZero))
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, point.y);
```

Of course this cannot distinguish between a truly empty path and a path that someone called `CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0)` on it.

(Actually, why you need to care? Just create a new path if you want an empty one.)

Answer (score 0):

a CGMutablePathRef is a pointer, so all you have to do to test this is:

```
if (NULL != path) {
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, point.y);
}
```

Comment: but there are many ways to write this. many people also choose `if (path)`, `if (path != NULL)`, and `if (0 != path)` -- they all produce the same results.